# Error in Android SQLite cursor

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, cursor

I get a runtime error with this code. Whats my mistake?

```
String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
Cursor cur = myDataBase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM  personel" , null);    
cur.moveToFirst();
cur.close();
myDataBase.close();
```

this is my logcat:

this is my logcat:

```
03-06 14:35:14.821: E/AndroidRuntime(11995): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-06 14:35:14.821: E/AndroidRuntime(11995): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{Dic.proj.pkg/Dic.proj.pkg.DictionaryActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: personel: , while compiling: Select * from personel
03-06 14:35:14.821: E/AndroidRuntime(11995):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
03-06 14:35:14.821: E/AndroidRuntime(11995):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
03-06 14:35:14.821: E/AndroidRuntime(11995):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
03-06 14:35:14.821: E/AndroidRuntime(11995):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
03-06 14:35:14.821: E/AndroidRuntime(11995):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-06 14:35:14.821: E/AndroidRuntime(11995):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-06 14:35:14.821: E/AndroidRuntime(11995):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
03-06 14:35:14.821: E/AndroidRuntime(11995):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-06 14:35:14.821: E/AndroidRuntime(11995):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
03-06 14:35:14.821: E/AndroidRuntime(11995):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
03-06 14:35:14.821: E/AndroidRuntime(11995):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
03-06 14:35:14.821: E/AndroidRuntime(11995):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-06 14:35:14.821: E/AndroidRuntime(11995): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: personel: , while compiling: Select * from personel
03-06 14:35:14.821: E/AndroidRuntime(11995):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
03-06 14:35:14.821: E/AndroidRuntime(11995):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:92)
03-06 14:35:14.821: E/AndroidRuntime(11995):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:65)
03-06 14:35:14.821: E/AndroidRuntime(11995):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:83)
03-06 14:35:14.821: E/AndroidRuntime(11995):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:49)
03-06 14:35:14.821: E/AndroidRuntime(11995):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:42)
03-06 14:35:14.821: E/AndroidRuntime(11995):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1356)
03-06 14:35:14.821: E/AndroidRuntime(11995):    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1324)
03-06 14:35:14.821: E/AndroidRuntime(11995):    at Dic.proj.pkg.DataBaseHelper.getCount(DataBaseHelper.java:126)
03-06 14:35:14.821: E/AndroidRuntime(11995):    at Dic.proj.pkg.DictionaryActivity.onCreate(DictionaryActivity.java:44)
03-06 14:35:14.821: E/AndroidRuntime(11995):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-06 14:35:14.821: E/AndroidRuntime(11995):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
```

Comment: **What** error are you getting?

Comment: post the error log... the picture is too vague.

Comment: when i run my program i don't get any error in Error Log. but in emulator i get this error: The Application App_name has stopped unexpectedly. please try again

Comment: Debug it and find where the error starts?

Comment: you should place the logcat so that someone could help you

Comment: @AviKumarManku i added my logcat on the main question ( edit)

Comment: 03-06 14:35:14.821: E/AndroidRuntime(11995): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: personel , this might be a typing error check spelling of  table name does personel it match to the actual table

Comment: `no such table: personel` Have you created the database correctly in the `onCreate` method of your database class?

Comment: Verify that you created the table first and it may be a spelling mistake in `personel`, because the correct spell is `personnel`. double check that your table (if already created, its) name is also the same as you using in query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have included the "personel" table recently & not upgraded the database version OR you may have changed the defenition of "personel" so try to increase the DataBase-Version here:

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context) 
{
    super(context, dbName, null,Increment the value here);
}
```